# Make Anaconda Programs Respect System Theme

Tags: anaconda

I'm using Spyder, Jupyter, and RStudio from the Anaconda Distribution (OS: Linux Mint 18), and I'm struggling with the fact that the Anaconda programs do not respect the system wide-theme. I've got a migraine problem which is exacerbated by bright white light, so everything else on my computer is the darkest theme I can make it.

I've looked at some of the threads on "dark theme for Spyder" (such as [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2350) one on the Spyder GitHub), but I would like this to be a more holistic fix for all the Anaconda applications.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of these projects are developed by different teams, so you'll have to contact/modify each of them individually.